# Add a tag into an element

Tags: javascript, html

I have some html like this

```
<div>111222333</div>
```

I want to use js to make it to

```
<div>111<strong>222</strong>333</div>
```

or something thing like

```
<div>111<strong class='aa'>222</strong>333</div>
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is the criteria used here to divide the content of that ``div`` for example take each three characters and wrap them up with an html element ?

Answer (score 0):

one solution

```js
var el = document.getElementById('text');
var val = el.innerHTML
el.innerHTML = val.replace(/(222)/g ,'<strong class="aa">$1</strong>')

document.write( el.parentNode.id );
```

```css
.aa{
  color : red;
  background : #EEE;
  }
```

```html
<div id='iam_parent'>
  <div id='text'>111222333</div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i am not sure how to get the selected part according to the father element.It means when i selected text and how can i know the father element

Comment: @a86356 i have updated my answer to reflect your needs.